# How do I change the string value based on what it contains in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let’s say I want to show different copy (e.g “shoes”) depending on the text in the string `{variant_prod.title}`

So for example:

```
   if (variant_prod_title == 'Nike air shoes' ) { 
        Change so "shoes" will be the only thing showing in the string
        else if (variant_prod_title == 'Nike air t-shirt' ) {
        Change so "t-shirt" will be the only thing showing in the string
    } 
        }
```

Here’s how the code looks like for me in my react component, how do change so it only shows “shoes” for example?

```
<span class="uppsell-add-to-cart-copy">{variant_prod.title}</span>
```

Comment: If you require this to happen only for `shoes` and `t-shirt`, it is too easy. In the `<span>` instead of `{variant_prod.title}` use this: `{variant_prod.title.includes('shoes') ? 'shoes' : variant_prod.title.includes('t-shirt') ? 't-shirt' : variant_prod.title}`. You may even choose to do this: `{variant_prod.title.split(' ').slice(-1)}`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve this in a way that it doesn't matter if your title is 'Nike air shoes' or 'Puma shoes'. As long as it includes shoes or t-shirt the displayed value will be set accordingly.

```
// this sets the initial value to the entire string
let displayedValue = variant_prod.title;

// this if checks if the word e.g. 'shoes' or 't-shirt' is present in the title
if (variant_prod.title.includes('shoes')) {
    displayedValue = 'shoes';
}    
else if (variant_prod.title.includes('t-shirt')) {
    displayedValue = 't-shirt';
}

return (
    <span class="uppsell-add-to-cart-copy">{displayedValue}</span>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to implement what you are looking for is by using [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

It's a good practice to use strict comparison "===" and declare your comparisons in a variable.

You can try the following code by using ES6:

```js
const NIKE_AIR_SHOES = 'Nike air shoes';
const NIKE_AIR_TSHIRT = 'Nike air t-shirt';

<span class="uppsell-add-to-cart-copy">
  {variant_prod.title === NIKE_AIR_SHOES
    ? "Shoes"
    : variant_prod.title === NIKE_AIR_TSHIRT
    ? "t-shirt"
    : ""}
</span>
```

You can also use the [Logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) as well as the [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operator to implement this.

```js
<span class="uppsell-add-to-cart-copy">
  {(variant_prod.title === NIKE_AIR_SHOES && "Shoes") ||
    (variant_prod.title === NIKE_AIR_TSHIRT && "t-shirt") ||
    ""}
</span>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your title has consistent structure and always have the output as the third value in the string then you can simply use

```
<span class="uppsell-add-to-cart-copy">{variant_prod.title.split(' ')[2]}</span>
```

`variant_prod.title.split(' ')` will convert the title into an array of 3 elements and you can use whatever value you want

'Nike air shoes' will return `shoes`

'Nike air t-shirt' will return `t-shirt`

'Nike air anything-else' will return `anything-else`